# Working with static methods in PHPUnit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am working with a third party library (therefore cannot change the usage of static method calls) which is ORM. Now in order for it to work my 'entity' class has to extend their entity class which inherits a couple of dependies using static methods, I want to test my entity class abstracting out these static calls, but unsure how

Code is as follows:

```
// Entity class ripped from third party library
class Entity
{
    // other methods etc

    /**
     * Setter for field properties
     */
    public function __set($field, $value)
    {
        $fields = $this->fields();
        if(isset($fields[$field])) {
            // Ensure value is set with type handler
            $typeHandler = Config::typeHandler($fields[$field]['type']);
            $value = $typeHandler::set($this, $value);
        }
        $this->_dataModified[$field] = $value;
    }
}

// my Entity class
class User extends Entity
{

    public static function fields()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => array('type' => 'int', 'primary' => true, 'serial' => true),
            'fullname' => array('type' => 'string', 'required' => false),
            'email_address' => array('type' => 'string', 'required' => true, 'email' => true),
        );
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->fullname = 'John Doe'; // dependancy on Config::typeHandler
```

Now I want to mock the Config object allowing me to set the variable, how do i do this?

Thanks